# CakePHP paginate causing weird DISTINCT behavior

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

I have a pretty basic paginate query which works fine until I put DISTINCT on one of the columns.

The following works:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(Message.recipient_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
    'fields' => array(
        'DISTINCT Message.sender_id',
        'Message.recipient_id',
        'Message.thread_id',
    ),
    'limit' => 15,
    'order' => array('Message.created' => 'DESC')
);
```

This query doesn't work:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(Message.recipient_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
    'fields' => array(
        'DISTINCT Message.sender_id',
        'Message.recipient_id',
        'Message.thread_id',
        // If I add any of the following columns, the DISTINCT doesn't work at all
        'Message.created',
        'Message.modified',
        'Message.id'
    ),
    'limit' => 15,
    'order' => array('Message.created' => 'DESC')
);
```

Why would any of those other columns in the 'fields' option trip up the DISTINCT keyword?

It doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean by "it doesn't work" that despite the distinct column you are getting multiple messages with the same sender_id...  Then the reason for that is because when using multiple columns with the distinct keyword, it looks for unique combinations of all the columns.  Message.created, Message.modified, and Message.id are going to be unique per row most or all of of the time, so those columns by themselves will make your combinations of fields distinct.  Try using group by Message.sender_id instead.

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(Message.recipient_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
    'fields' => array(
        'Message.sender_id',
        'Message.recipient_id',
        'Message.thread_id',
        'Message.created',
        'Message.modified',
        'Message.id'
    ),
    'limit' => 15,
    'order' => array('Message.created' => 'DESC'),
    'group' => array('Message.sender_id'),
);
```

Comment: I did use 'group' at first, but then 'order' got ignored. But at least now I understand why DISTINCT doesn't work in this case. Is it possible to just apply the DISTINCT keyword to one column so that it does work?

Or is there an alternative solution to this? It's pretty frustrating.

Comment: As far as I know, if you use `group by x order by x`, in a mysql query, it will be ordered.  Perhaps the query cakePHP is generating is not including the order by.  So you should check to see what actual query it's creating.